# Creating a complex layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Please take a look at the concept design for a simple app that I am trying to create. 
[image]

I know for sure I can accomplish this on 1 device using the RelativeLayout, but of course making this consistent on many  devices is going to be very difficult.

Please let me know your thoughts on how to best accomplish this kind of layout.

Comment: What technologies are you using? Native mobile? HTML? CSS? Please add the appropriate tags.

Comment: I'm just using the Android SDK, I am creating my layouts via xml in the layout-normal folder. I thought this was the only way to design a layout for Android Activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you on all screens, change the last `LinearLayout`'s background to the Circle texture you have:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" > 
<LinearLayout   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="0.5" >
         <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" 
         android:layout_weight="0.5"
         android:background="@android:color/holo_purple">
         </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" 
         android:layout_weight="0.5"
         android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">
         </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="0.5" >
         <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" 
         android:layout_weight="0.5"
         android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">
         </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" 
         android:layout_weight="0.5"
         android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">
         </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout   
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/title_gray_background"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >
     </LinearLayout>        
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you choose .5 as the weight and not 1 for each linearlayout, is there some benefit to doing that way?

Comment: No, not really... you can set 1 for all of them and the result should be the same. I find it easier to understand it that way.